# OnClicklistener on a added View in a Linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

Here's my problem:

I added an ImageView to a Linear Layout. Now I want to set an OnClickListener to this ImageView. But there is no reaction. So I think the Listener got lost when the View was added to the Layout.

Here is my Code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
        ImageView a1,a2;
        LinearLayout Row1;

        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
            LinearLayout Row1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Row1);
            ImageView a1 = new ImageView(this);
    ImageView a2 = new ImageView(this);
            a1.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
    a2.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            a1.setOnClickListener(this);
    a2.setOnClickListener(this);
            Row1.addView(a1, params);
    Row1.addView(a2, params);
        }

        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (v.getId() == a1.getId()){
                    Status.setText("A1 clicked");
                }
if (v.getId() == a2.getId()){
                    Status.setText("A2 clicked");
                }
    }
        }
```

Now I get a NullPointerException, when I click on a1.
I removed all not relevant code and I hope someone can help me out ;)

Comment: could you post your full code ?? and code for handling  onClick method

Comment: i will try...one moment ;)

Comment: you are comparing pointers, try for example v.getId() == a1.getId() or loose if so you can see for yourself that that is a problem. Hope this helps and enjoy your work

Comment: hmm now i get a NullPointerException...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got ***Null Pointer Exception*** because

You have declared your **LinearLayout** as

```
LinearLayout Row1;
```

And after that on oncreate() method you again declared it by

```
LinearLayout Row1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Row1);
```

So at this it would be conflicted here

```
Row1.addView(a1, params);
Row1.addView(a2, params);
```

So just change this from

```
LinearLayout Row1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Row1);
```

to

```
Row1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Row1);
```

and also this

```
Row1.addView(a1, params);
Row1.addView(a2, params);
a1.setOnClickListener(this);
a2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

First try removing the conditional check (v == a1) to see whether the event is being fired at all. In your code, you're making a static reference to **Row** and not **Row1**, your instance. Try adding the view to **Row1**.

Comment: What happens if you get Row1 to set your Activity as the onClickListener?

Comment: I have more added ImageViews in this LinearLayout. So I need one onClickListener for every ImageView.

Comment: I understand, but is the event fired?

Comment: Don't know. I dont think so, because i had no reaction bevore i changed to v.getId() == a1.getId()

Comment: Try eliminating these unknowns. Just see if you can get the event to fire at all. Don't perform the conditional checks, and just attempt to set the text of your views or use Log.d("your tag","fired"); as soon as the event is launched. Also try implementing OnTouchListener instead of OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

Set onClickListener() after adding ImageView to the Layout.Like:

```
ImageView a1 = new ImageView(this);
ImageView a2 = new ImageView(this);
a1.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
a2.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
Row1.addView(a1, params);
Row1.addView(a2, params);
a1.setOnClickListener(this);
a2.setOnClickListener(this);
```